# How to parse complex json in python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, json

I trying to list the names of my puppet classes from a Puppet Enterprise 3.7 puppet master, using Puppet's REST API.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json

url='https://ppt-001.example.com:4433/classifier-api/v1/groups'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data={}
cacert='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem'
key='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/ppt-001.example.com.pem'
cert='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ppt-001.example.com.pem'
result = requests.get(url,
        data=data, #no data needed for this request
        headers=headers, #dict {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        cert=(cert,key), #key/cert pair 
        verify=cacert
        )
print json.dumps( result.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')) 
for i in result.json:
    print i
```

Here is the error message I get when I execute the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add-group.py", line 42, in <module>
    for i in result.json:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

Here is a sample of the data I get back from the REST API:

```
[
    {
        "classes": {},
        "environment": "production",
        "environment_trumps": false,
        "id": "00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000",
        "name": "default",
        "parent": "00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000",
        "rule": [
            "and",
            [
                "~",
                "name",
                ".*"
            ]
        ],
        "variables": {}
    },
    {
        "classes": {
            "puppet_enterprise": {
                "certificate_authority_host": "ppt-001.example.com",
                "console_host": "ppt-001.example.com",
                "console_port": "443",
                "database_host": "ppt-001.example.com",
                "database_port": "5432",
                "database_ssl": true,
                "mcollective_middleware_hosts": [
                    "ppt-001.example.com"
                ],
                "puppet_master_host": "ppt-001.example.com",
                "puppetdb_database_name": "pe-puppetdb",
                "puppetdb_database_user": "pe-puppetdb",
                "puppetdb_host": "ppt-001.example.com",
                "puppetdb_port": "8081"
            }
        },
        "environment": "production",
        "environment_trumps": false,
        "id": "52c479fe-3278-4197-91ea-9127ba12474e",
        "name": "PE Infrastructure",
        "parent": "00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000",
        "variables": {}
    },
.
.
.
```

How should I go about access the `name` key and getting the values like `default` and `PE Infrastructure`?

I have read the other answers here on SO saying that one should use `json.loads()` and I have tried using `parsed_json = json.loads(result.json())` but results in this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add-group.py", line 38, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(result.json())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: `result.json` is a method, `result.json()` is value returned from a method. AFAIR result.json() is already Python object (dict / list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print json.dumps( result.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` 
the first parameter of json.dumps must be a string or buffer, as stated by the TypeError your getting (`TypeError: expected string or buffer`).

Your variable result is an instance of `Response`, and the method .json() will return a dictionary. Since you're passing the result of `.json()` to `json.dumps()`, you're getting an error. You could either just use `result.json()` which is already a dictionary corresponding to your response, or change your json.dumps line to `print json.dumps( result.text, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` where `result.text` is your JSON result as a string/unicode.

After the change, to access something like the `name` attribute, you could do something like:

```
for item in r.json():
    try:
        print item['name']
    expect KeyError:
        print "There is no 'name' attribute"
```